# "Carousel" animation for text in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make a "text carousel", just like the music title in this gif, how do I do this with flutter?

[image: music gif]

Answer (score 0):

To get it done, you need to use marquee,  a package from pub.dev

Use the link below
https://pub.dev/packages/marquee

You will see the ReadMe, to install.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).